# Installation of hibernate tools in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I used this  link http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/ for the JBoss site.

From above mentioned link I downloaded the entire JBoss Tools 3.2.0,
Hibernate Tools (HT) from Application Development,
HT from Data Services,
JBoss Maven Hibernate Configurator from Maven Support and
HT from Web and Java EE Development. But i am not able to install hibernate tool. Is their any other way to do it. I got error while installing it from above links.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Indigo, simply go to "help=>Eclipse Market Place" type jboss tools/ hibernate tools in Search, You will get list. Select HT from list and click on install/update link. Eclipse will automatically install it.

For Eclipse Galileo, Download zip [from jboss](http://www.jboss.org/tools/download/stable/3_1_GA.html), copy and paste the contents of zip file into your eclipse folder.(Keep backup of your eclipse). There are two directories features and plugins in zip file. copy contents of each directory and paste it in your features and plugins directories(under Eclipse's home directory).

And ofcourse, Restart your eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse SDK
I am using galileo
Version: 3.5.2